# Is there any equivalent method of postUrl method of android webview in Crosswalk webview?

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I have integrated Crosswalk webview in one of my android application. I need to send formdata to web URL by using HTTP POST method. I tried searching but could not find equivalent method of `void postUrl (String url, byte[] postData)` method provided by default android webview in the crosswalk webview documentation. It will be great if someone can help me in identifying how to achieve this above mentioned implementation.

Comment: Currently I'm facing the same problem. Could you please tell me if you found a solution?

Comment: @AlexanderZarovniy I could not find any inbuilt method to handle this. I implemented it on my own, It is more of a workaround. I made an HTTP Post call explicitly by using HTTPUrlConnection class, store the response in String object & load it in CrossWalk webview by using public void load(java.lang.String url, java.lang.String content) method. Hope this helps!